# Getting all logs of different class in one file

Tags: java, logging, properties, configuration

I am trying to get all logs of different class in one file. I am using log4j2 and properties file for configuration.my configuration file is as below.
Here test class and impl  class is the implementation class contains code.please help.

Problem is it is not showing logs for test class.it is only showing logs for impl class.

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}[%t]%c{1}-%msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=com.package.metadata.test
logger.file.name=com.package.metadataservice.impl
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Comment: what is the actual problem here if you need help to be specific please check here (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Dear, it is not writing logs for metadata.test class. only writing logs for metadataservice.impl class.

Comment: why dont you write single property file for each class

Comment: It has been solved. i am sharing it with you. we can add multiple class logs in one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.Append=true
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
loggers=file1,file2,file3,file4
logger.file1.name=test
logger.file1.level = debug
logger.file1.appenderRefs = file
logger.file1.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

logger.file2.name=metadataservice.impl
logger.file2.level = debug
logger.file2.appenderRefs = file
logger.file2.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

logger.file3.name=db.connector
logger.file3.level = debug
logger.file3.appenderRefs = file
logger.file3.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

    logger.file4.name=metadatareader
    logger.file4.level = debug
    logger.file4.appenderRefs = file
    logger.file4.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```